# MySQL query "in (a, b, c)", how to return elements in this same order (a, b then c)?

Tags: mysql

Searching a table for precise elements by their ID in a precise order, how can I use this kind of request:

```
select * from TABLE where ID in (1, 7, 2)
```

To sort elements in the order I requested them (`ID = 1` then `ID = 7` then `ID = 2`) ? Just as the following :

```
TABLE
ID | field1 | ...
1  | value  | ...
7  | value  | ...
2  | value  | ...
```

Given of course that the requested order isn't a natural order of one of the fields (can't do `order by field` to get the result).

Comment: Try `ORDER BY CASE ID WHEN 1 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 3 END`

Answer (score 1):

use **FIELDS** as below

```
select * from TABLE where ID in (1, 7, 2) ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 1, 7, 2)
```